# How to write the relation for a graph in graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory

I've been given these graphs and I need to write the relations for them. Could you pleas let me know how this can be done? I can write the edge relations <1,2> <1,4> <1,6>,... but I think something different is being asked here

[image]

Comment: You have drawn in arrows pointing from each node to itself. Are they actually supposed to be there? And yes, they want you to notice some pattern in the arrows, and want you to write something compact like $a\leq b$ (which is almost right for both of them, but not quite).

Comment: @Arthur No, those arrow's shouldn't be there. I don't see the pattern in the 1st one but in the second one each node goes to the one above it and the one above that but how should I depict that? I mean in the edge relation there are two elements <a,b> first one is the edge we map and the other is where it goes. Here I don't know  what notation to use and what should represent what

Answer (score 1):

You have found the pattern in the second one. You say "each node goes to the one above it and the one above that". If $a$ is the start of the arrow and $b$ is the end of the arrow, what does that tell you about the quantity $b-a$? Write that down, and you have your answer. And don't forget to fill in $B = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$.

The pattern in the first one is divisibility. The arrows point to multiples. Since the drawn in arrows aren't really part of the picture, it gets a little more awkward to describe, but I would maybe go for something like "$a\neq b$ and $a\mid b$", or maybe "$\frac ba$ is an integer larger than $1$". Again, don't forget the $A = \{\_\_\_\}$ field.